# Fragment detached from activity without any obvious reason

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've a fragment, and that fragment includes a ViewPager.

If a callback is triggered in the fragment with data from the server, sometimes the fragment loses its Activity.

I'm getting the following error while trying to get the fragment's activity:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.

What could cause this ?

Comment: post code here..

Answer (score 0):

In Http network libraries (like Retrofit), Callbacks (`onResponse()`, `OnError()`) runs on `MainThread` without knowing, if there is `Fragment` attached to an `Activity` or not?

So if you are trying to perform UI operation, It will through `java.lang.IllegalStateException` which result in App crash.

**Solution:-**
You can check if the `Fragment` is added or not before performing any operation,

```
if (isAdded()) {
   //.. perform your operation here...
}
```